# Configure Maven to use different repository managers based on what project is executed?

Tags: maven, nexus

I work as a consultat for two different companies that both use maven and that both have their own nexus repository managers. I have used maven with both repository managers and it works fine but every time I switch customer I need to change my settings.xml file where the address for the repository manager is located.

Is there a way to go around this? To make Maven figure out what repository mangager to use based on what project I am building? I can easily edit the pom-files in both projects and activate different profiles if that is needed.

Comment: Seems like you might already know the answer but you could just activate a profile on the command line (`mvn -P company1`) and put the different configuration under separate [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles)  in the `settings.xml` file

Comment: This would work but I was hoping on a solution where I would be able to make the projects know what repository manager to use without me having to specify it at each invocation of maven. If that is not possible, I will use this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers, however I finally had a different approach, and that was to disable the central repository and add the projects nexus repository in each pom.

The downside of this is that if it is to work fully, it needs to be in **every** pom, not just the parent.

However, it is a one-time configuration for each project and the only thing each developer needs to add to their settings.xml is their credentials for the nexus repo which makes the startup for new developers simpler.

Another downside is that if I run maven outside of a project, like `archetype:generate` maven is not aware of my nexus repo and I need to specify that on the command line. I believe I could configure a default repo in my settings.xml but I haven't explored that further.

I also never have to think about which project I am working on, when I run maven the project knows which repository to use and this is **very** important to me.

I suspect that not everyone may agree that this is the best solution but it works for me and the overhead is acceptable.

This is how my configuration in each pom looks like

```
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>my-nexus-repo</id>
        <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com/content/groups/private/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>my-nexus-repo</id>
        <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com/content/groups/private/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to put .m2/ under control of VCS like Git and change the settings by using a different branch (ignore the repository itself).

```
git checkout CUSTOMER1

git checkout CUSTOMER2
```

That's my current solution. Very simple and effective and furthermore every change i make to my settings.xml is under version control.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation I suspect I'd use different logins when working on each customer. This would not be very convenient for your personal stuff (e.g. email account), but I'd feel safer knowing that everything is kept separate.

On the other hand if this is not a worry, you might consider setting up Nexus on your machine as a proxy for both your customers' repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set up a local copy of Nexus that you run as a proxy on your machine. From that you proxy both external repositories.

Then in terms of deploying to the different repositories you will not need to do anything since they use different url already in the projects distribution management.

If you absolutely have to separate them I would suggest to use two different settings.xml files that separate it all and invoke mvn with -s specifying the correct settings file.

For convenience you can create a shell aliases for those invocations.

If you use the same settings.xml and profiles in their you do not have the same separation but it will also work. You can then also create a aliases to make things cleaner..